# How do I make Apache follow symlinks in an OSX / XAMPP environment?

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, xampp, symlink

I've been trying to get Apache to follow symlinks. I am getting an "Access forbidden!" message.

I understand this is likely a permissions issue.

So far I have tried:

- Setting the source directory to chmod 777
- Adding the xampp/apache user 'nobody' to the groups 'admin' and 'staff'
- Both symlink and apache alias directives (both give me the forbidden message)

Source:

> 1228833 drwxr-xr-x  27 eric  staff    918 Jun  1 09:55 .
>     332009 drwxr-xr-x+ 40 eric  staff   1360 May 22 10:41 ..
>    1228879 -rw-r--r--@  1 eric  staff  24580 Jun  1 09:55 .DS_Store
>   30604402 lrwxr-xr-x   1 eric  staff     93 Jun  1 09:07 YellowFinTunaPages -> /Users/ericmiller/Dropbox/_iSirona/iSirona Product Development/Prototypes/YellowFinTunaPages/

Destination:

> 30602721 drwxr-xr-x   4 eric  staff   136 Jun  1 09:10 .
>   1286885 drwxr-xr-x@ 11 eric  staff   374 Jun  1 09:04 ..
>   30606068 -rw-r--r--@  1 eric  staff  6148 Jun  1 09:10 .DS_Store
>   30602745 drwxrwxrwx  10 eric  staff   340 Jun  1 09:05 YellowFinTunaPages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out access permissions for a folder depend on the folder above it. I didn't realize this. I had to chmod 755 the whole preceding directory tree. I wish there were a better solution--I don't actually want to allow broad access to that whole tree, just the subfolder.

[Apache won't follow symlinks (403 Forbidden)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381371/apache-wont-follow-symlinks-403-forbidden)