# Apache won't follow symlink

Tags: apache, symlink

I've checked out the best answer to this question and can't get it to work.  Using Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache 2.4.7 I am trying to load
`localhost/locals/hcl/index.html` in order to verify that it works correctly through a server.
Where

```
/var/www/html/locals -> /media/userid/WWW/www/upload
```

and `/media/userid/WWW/www/upload/hcl/index.html` exists. 
I have changed `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to (following is copied from webmin output for the default server):

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
 Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

as recommended in 
[Apache won't follow symlinks (403 Forbidden)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381371/apache-wont-follow-symlinks-403-forbidden)
and all directories and files in the path have `rwx` set and `/media/userid/WWW/www/upload` has owner set to `www-data`, which used to be important.
My `/var/www/html` directory contains another symbolic link:

```
phpsysinfo -> /usr/share/phpsysinfo
```

that does work, and

```
file:///media/userid/WWW/www/upload/hcl/index.html
```

works as expected in Firefox.  Obviously, I have omitted some crucial step, but I cannot see what it is: can anyone advise ?

Comment: Does `file:///var/www/html/locals/hcl/index.html` work in forefox? is there anything in apache error_log?

Comment: Dusan... yes, yes:  `AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/locals` ... basically confirms error 403 returned to browser.  Thanks for interest.