# Symbolic link causing 403 forbidden error

Tags: apache, laravel, vagrant, laravel-5, centos7

So I am trying to build a custom vagnt box with Laravel 5.2 on CentOS 7.2. I successfully created a vagrant box running centos and installed LAMP stack and composer on it. Also, I am using laravel installer to create Laravel 5.2 projects with composer as described [here][1]. Now from here I have tried two different methods:

1. ### Create new laravel project as `sudo` on `/var/www/html`

   I ran `sudo laravel new <project name>` and it created `/var/www/html/<project name>`. Added this to `httpd.conf`:

   `Alias /MyLaravel /var/www/html/<project name>/public
   <VirtualHost *:80>
          DocumentRoot /var/www/html<project name>/public
          <Directory /var/www/html/<project name>>
                 AllowOverride All
          </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>`

   With following permissions set:

   1. `chmod 775 /var/www/html/<project name>/storage`
   2. `sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/<project name>`
   3. `sudo chmod 755 /var/www`

   > Everything works fine. No issues.
2. ### Create new laravel project in home directory and use symbolic link to `/var/www/html`

   I have run:
   `laravel new <project name>` 
   in home directory and it created `/home/vagrant/<project name>` then I have created a symbolic link using:
   `ln -s /home/vagrant/<project name> /var/www/html`. Now I have same permissions and configurations on httpd.conf.

   > This time I get the error: Forbidden
   >   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I assume there is some configuration that I am missing. I have tried changing both original and symbolic link permissions and adding symlink options in httpd.conf with no success. Please kindly help.

Respose 1: Output of `ls -al /var/www/html/<project name>`

`drwxrwxr-x. 11 apache  apache    4096 Jul 19 21:25 .
drwx------.  7 vagrant vagrant   4096 Jul 19 21:24 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 10 apache  apache    4096 Jul 19 21:24 app
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache  apache    1646 Jul 19 21:24 artisan
drwxrwxr-x.  3 apache  apache      51 Jul 19 21:24 bootstrap
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache  apache    1272 Jul 19 21:24 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache  apache  113359 Jul 19 21:24 composer.lock
drwxrwxr-x.  2 apache  apache    4096 Jul 19 21:24 config
drwxrwxr-x.  5 apache  apache      68 Jul 19 21:24 database
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache  apache     478 Jul 19 21:25 .env
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache  apache     443 Jul 19 21:24 .env.example
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache  apache      61 Jul 19 21:24 .gitattributes
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache  apache      73 Jul 19 21:24 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache  apache     503 Jul 19 21:24 gulpfile.js
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache  apache     212 Jul 19 21:24 package.json
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache  apache    1026 Jul 19 21:24 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxr-x.  2 apache  apache      90 Jul 19 21:24 public
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache  apache    1918 Jul 19 21:24 readme.md
drwxrwxr-x.  5 apache  apache      42 Jul 19 21:24 resources
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache  apache     567 Jul 19 21:24 server.php
drwxrwxr-x.  5 apache  apache      43 Jul 19 21:24 storage
drwxrwxr-x.  2 apache  apache      47 Jul 19 21:24 tests
drwxrwxr-x. 29 apache  apache    4096 Jul 19 21:25 vendor`

P.S. Here are links I have already explored:

1. [Apache won't follow symlinks (403 Forbidden)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381371/apache-wont-follow-symlinks-403-forbidden)
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/142084/apache-gives-403-forbidden

Comment: Can you run `ls -al /var/www/html/<project name>` and update the question with the output?

Comment: @Sam updated. Thanks.