# Trying to have files from a usb in an apache web server

Tags: html, apache, raspberry-pi, webserver

I have a web server set up on my raspberry pi and i have a file on a usb that i would to keep on the usb and use in the web server. i have all the files i normally use in /var/www/html/ which is the default location. i have including the following in apache2.conf

```
<Directory /media/pi/ESD-USB/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

im sure i have done somthing wrong here but im not sure what and i cant find an answer anywhere

Comment: You haven't said what you are doing (e.g. making a request to the server), what you expect to happen or what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you have in your default directory settings set `FollowSimLinks`, you can just create simbolic link to `/media/pi/ESD-USB/` in `/var/www/html/` and it should work.

Comment: i just did that but i get a 403 error whenever i try to go to website/usb.

Comment: there can be issue with permisions for that folder.  See this post please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381371/apache-wont-follow-symlinks-403-forbidden/67188746#67188746